# Error "No file format header found." running NuGet restore

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package-restore

When I run

```
Nuget.exe restore [path]\packages.config -PackagesDirectory [path]\build\packages
```

it works as expected. However, the command

```
Nuget.exe restore [path]\bigpackages.config -PackagesDirectory [path]\build\packages
```

fails with the error:

**No file format header found.**

This is the case, even if I copy the packages.config file and rename it to bigpackages.config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the name **packages.config** is expected, but any other config file name is rejected.

My solution was to put my bigpackages.config file in a subfolder, using the accepted filename. This command succeeds:

```
Nuget.exe restore [path]\big\packages.config -PackagesDirectory [path]\build\packages
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use NuGet v3 which appears to correctly handle such files.

It was [NuGet 2.8](http://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.8) to introduce support for *Individual packages.config Files for Different Platforms* but even 2.8.6 correcltly handles them only within the *solution restore procedure*.

As I undestand all files with names other than **exactly** `packages.config` are treated as solution files. And the error is produced by the MSBuild run internally by the NuGet.